# HTML + CSS layout with bottom box showing all content, variable height top box with scroll

Tags: html, css

- I want two boxes, one on top of the other.
- The bottom box should take as much height as it needs to display its entire content (I don't know how much height this content will take).
- The top box should fill the remaining height of the container, generating scroll for its content if necessary.

[image: Working example]

This fiddle is a working example of what I described above: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielmaldi/q258g40y/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-component">
    <div class="my-component_top-content">
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.
    </div>
    <div class="my-component_bottom-content">
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 320px;
}

.my-component {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: lightblue;
}

.my-component_top-content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;

  background-color: green;
}

.my-component_bottom-content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;

  background-color: orange;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome (up until version 49) and Safari. The problem is that it breaks in Chrome 50 and above (you can browse the fiddle in Chrome Canary and see for yourself).

I filed this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594376 and there's been some discussion going on. But maybe this isn't a regression in Chrome as per the CSS spec (the Chrome 49 behavior doesn't match Firefox, while the Chrome 50 behavior does).

I haven't been able to find a way to achieve what I want that works in Chrome Canary (or Firefox, which although I don't specifically need to support, maybe a layout that works in Firefox will also work in newer Chrome versions).

**So, how could I achieve what I described in the three initial bullets, and which works in Safari, Chrome 49, and Chrome 50 (Canary)?**

**EDIT:** I need to support older Android Stock Browser, so it's best if this can be achieved without `display: flex;` which doesn't have very good support there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update based on comment/requirement for older browser support, here is a `display: table` version

*Update 2 and does now work on Webkit (Canary inlcuded), Firefox, Edge, IE11*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.my-component {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.my-component-top {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
.my-component-top-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
  /* IE11 fix - need block */
  _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .my-component-top-cell { display: block; }

.my-component-top-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.my-component-bottom {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-component">
    <div class="my-component-top">
      <div class="my-component-top-cell">
        <div class="my-component-top-inner">
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
          Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-component-bottom">
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For modern browsers, use `flex` like this, where the top box has `flex: 1` to fill the remaining space and bottom box has `flex: 0` to make it take as little as possible of the available space.

Also I added a `min-height: 20px;` on the top box in case the content in the bottom box gets to big (prevent it from disappear completely).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.my-component {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.my-component_top-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.my-component_bottom-content {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-component">
    <div class="my-component_top-content">
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
      Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.<br>
    </div>
    <div class="my-component_bottom-content">
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I updated my fiddle with `flex` and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q258g40y/5/ Is there a way to achieve this without `flex`? I didn't mention in my question (now edited) that I need to support older Android Stock Browser which has bad support for `flex`. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I just tried your example and my fiddle in Safari and it doesn't work fine, so I'm kind of "afraid" of `flex`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I found that your update answer (2nd example) only works because of `min-height: 50px` which is setting the box's height explicitly. However, I'm going to accept your first answer since, albeit using `display: flex`, it's a completely valid and working solution to my problem. Please, if you are able to do so, can you edit your answer to clarify this (the fact that the right solution is your first, and not edited, answer)? Thanks!

Comment: I thought I could accept multiple answers, but I just learnt I can't. So i'm going to choose dgrogan's solution because it works best in all browsers and doesn't use `display: flex`. Sorry about that. But I'm really grateful for your help! Thanks!

Comment: @gabrielmaldi I updated the order of samples. The `min-height: 50px`, now set to `20px` to make it look like _drogans_, doesn't have to be there and isn't an explicit height. Its only purpose is to not make the scroll div disappear completely, which in _drogans_ case is to small to be of matter anyway, as one can't read what's inside. ... Also, _drogans_ version does not work in Firefox, Edge, IE11, which mine does, so if you are going to stick to that, you should update your answer telling so, as when users will test it on FF/Edge/IE11 and find it not working, they might down vote it.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielmaldi/rsuzupbn/) with your first sample (the one with `display: table`) and verified it doesn't work in Chrome Canary. If you change `min-height: 20px` to, say, `min-height: 200px`, you'll get similar (albeit not perfect) behavior. If you remove `min-height` it doesn't work at all. That's why, in an earlier comment, I said that it worked because we were setting the height explicitly. I'll update the other answer with compatibility, thanks!

Comment: @gabrielmaldi I'm somewhat puzzled here, why do you build a non cross browser solution? .. I mean Chrome Canary is a developer's version and this issue will be gone when their stable version will hit the users?

Comment: As I stated in my question (after I edited it), I only need this to work on Safari, Chrome 49, and Chrome 50+. This is because I'm using this layout in iOS and Android WebViews, so I don't care about Firefox, IE, Edge, etc. Canary contains a change (a change, not an issue; link in my question) that will land in Stable, and when this happens, your solution (which currently works in Stable), won't work anymore. So I need something that works in Chrome 50+ (Canary right now) and is backwards compatible with older Chrome versions (49 and below), as well as Safari.

Comment: @gabrielmaldi I just now noticed a mistake I made in the `table` version (forgot setting `display: table-cell`), now updated, without `min-height`, and tested in Chrome Canary with success. Guess Canary won't treat anonymous objects the same way the older versions did.

Comment: @LGSon, you're right about anonymous objects. Children of anonymous objects that specify % height will now have their height treated as auto. It's what the spec calls for and what firefox does, so we did it too. Question though: any thoughts or hypotheses on why FF requires the relative/absolute dance that your solution has?

Comment: @dgrogan In none of Firefox, Edge, IE11, Chrome will a table-cell let `overflow: auto` generate a scroll when it reach 100%, it just continue to grow (max-height won't work either), so the only way to make that happen, without set height explicit of course, is to use an absolute positioned div like I did it, and make that one scroll (flexbox has the same issue actually, and same solution).

Comment: I was about to ask the same question @dgrogan did: why is `position: absolute;` necessary? Now that @LGSon clarified that, I'm going to accept his answer since it works on most browsers. (I'm still sticking to @dgrogan's solution for my scenario since I only need to support Chrome and Safari, and I find his solution cleaner without absolute positioning). Thank you both very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` to solve your problem:

```
.my-component {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.my-component_top-content {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.my-component_bottom-content {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg218mLe/1/)

Comment: @SlackBadger You'll need to adjust the height of the container if the child content is too large https://jsfiddle.net/yg218mLe/4/

Comment: @Kable thank you. I updated my fiddle with `flex` and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q258g40y/5/ Is there a way to achieve this without `flex`? I didn't mention in my question (now edited) that I need to support older Android Stock Browser which has bad support for `flex`. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I just tried your fiddle and mine in Safari and it doesn't work fine, so I'm kind of "afraid" of `flex`.

Comment: @Kable thank you so much for your help! I'm going to accept your answer since, albeit using `display: flex`, it's a completely valid and working solution to my problem.

Comment: I thought I could accept multiple answers, but I just learnt I can't. So i'm going to choose dgrogan's solution because it works best in all browsers and doesn't use `display: flex`. Sorry about that. But I'm really grateful for your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dgrogan` came up with this solution [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594376).

It works in Chrome 49, Chrome 50, and Safari 9, and it doesn't rely on `display: flex`. It doesn't work in Firefox, Edge, and IE11.

https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/1w3hmvph/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-component">
    <div class="td">
      <div class="my-component_top-content">
        Variable content that should fill the container and scroll.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-component_bottom-content">
      Variable content that should extend in height as much as needed.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 320px;
}

.my-component {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: lightblue;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.my-component_top-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;

  background-color: green;
}

.my-component_bottom-content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;

  background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change heights from % to px. height in % is not working.
2. overflow-y: scroll; for top content.
3. use jquery to solve it. css isn't made for calculating other DOM's

Comment: Thank you. I can't use fixed height (px) because I don't know it beforehand, the content always varies. And I want to use just HTML and CSS, not JS.

Comment: then answer is quite simple, don't waste your time. there is no solution.  CSS has no function stuff to play with DOM  , it's a lang to beautify. do calc for self and parent. and to solve your problem there is a need to calc other DOM , which is totally impossible. for HTML+CSS

Comment: It's very well possible, see the other answers.